# Flutter: how to select animation direction based on value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this animated container:

```
AnimatedContainer(
                  width: ScreenSize.getScreenWidth(context),
                  height: _selectAll ? 10 : bottomBarHeight,
                  color: _selectAll ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
                  duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                  curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                  child: const FlutterLogo(size: 75),
                ),
```

I want that when `_selectAll` is true, the container appears starting from bottom to top and when `_selectAll` is false, the container dissapears starting from top to bottom.

In this version the container behaves the exact opposite way (when false, goes bottom to top, when true goes top to bottom

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried AnimatedAlign widget?

Here is a sample code based on your code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyWidget()));
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool reverse = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Example'),
      ),
      body: AnimatedAlign(
        alignment: reverse ? Alignment.bottomCenter : Alignment.topCenter,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
        curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
        child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 100,
            color: reverse ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
            child: const FlutterLogo()),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            reverse = !reverse;
          });
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.flip),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER**
Wrap the container in a `Column` with `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,`

```
Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children:[
       AnimatedContainer(
          width: selected ? 300.0 : 300.0,
          height: selected ? 20 : 100.0,
          color: selected ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
          alignment:
              selected ? Alignment.bottomCenter : Alignment.topCenter,
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          child: FlutterLogo(),
        ),
      ]),
```